# How to replace GLSurfaceView with TextureView in Android Ice Cream Sandwich?

Tags: android

The TextureView [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html) states that it can be used to render OpenGL content.

In the [blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/11/android-40-graphics-and-animations.html) announcing TextureView, it states:

> A TextureView can just as easily be used to embed an OpenGL scene in your application. As of Android 4.0, eglCreateWindowSurface() can be used to render into a SurfaceTexture object.

Which seems to imply that to use TextureView instead of GLSurfaceView, one would have to do all the EGL setup themselves and manage the EGLContext and the threading (since GLSurfaceView maintains a GLThread). There doesn't seem to be any sample code in the Android 4.0 SDK that demonstrates how the "*TextureView can just as easily be used to embed an OpenGL scene*". TextureView seems to plug in more cleanly to the Camera preview (setPreviewTexture) and MediaPlayer (setSurface).

Is it possible to use GLSurfaceView in conjunction with TextureView by using GLSurfaceView.setEGLWindowSurfaceFactory to make it render to the TextureView's SurfaceTexture?

Again, it would be nice if there were some sample code.

Comment: FWIW, various examples can be found in Grafika (https://github.com/google/grafika).  For additional background, see https://source.android.com/devices/graphics.html .

Comment: This is a great discussion post about it: https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/android-developers/U5RXFGpAHPE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A moderator deleted this answer so adding it back for posterity:

See Romain Guy's answer (Nov 23rd 2011) from the android-dev google group:

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/539457146a401cf1 (mirrored: http://grokbase.com/t/gg/android-developers/11bqmgb7sw/how-to-replace-glsurfaceview-with-textureview-in-android-ice-cream-sandwich)

> GLSurfaceView handles GL setup for you, which TextureView will not do.
>   A TextureView can be used as the native window when you create an EGL
>   surface. Here is an example (the interesting part is the call to
>   eglCreateWindowSurface()):

```
 @Override
 public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
     mRenderThread = new RenderThread(getResources(), surface);
     mRenderThread.start();
 }

 private static class RenderThread extends Thread {
     private static final String LOG_TAG = "GLTextureView";

     static final int EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION = 0x3098;
     static final int EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT = 4;

     private volatile boolean mFinished;

     private final Resources mResources;
     private final SurfaceTexture mSurface;

     private EGL10 mEgl;
     private EGLDisplay mEglDisplay;
     private EGLConfig mEglConfig;
     private EGLContext mEglContext;
     private EGLSurface mEglSurface;
     private GL mGL;

     RenderThread(Resources resources, SurfaceTexture surface) {
         mResources = resources;
         mSurface = surface;
     }

     private static final String sSimpleVS =
             "attribute vec4 position;\n" +
             "attribute vec2 texCoords;\n" +
             "varying vec2 outTexCoords;\n" +
             "\nvoid main(void) {\n" +
             " outTexCoords = texCoords;\n" +
             " gl_Position = position;\n" +
             "}\n\n";
     private static final String sSimpleFS =
             "precision mediump float;\n\n" +
             "varying vec2 outTexCoords;\n" +
             "uniform sampler2D texture;\n" +
             "\nvoid main(void) {\n" +
             " gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture, outTexCoords);\n" +
             "}\n\n";

     private static final int FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES = 4;
     private static final int TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES = 5 * FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES;
     private static final int TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_POS_OFFSET = 0;
     private static final int TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_UV_OFFSET = 3;
     private final float[] mTriangleVerticesData = {
             // X, Y, Z, U, V
             -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
              1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
             -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
              1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
     };

     @Override
     public void run() {
         initGL();

         FloatBuffer triangleVertices = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(mTriangleVerticesData.length * FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
         triangleVertices.put(mTriangleVerticesData).position(0);

         int texture = loadTexture(R.drawable.large_photo);
         int program = buildProgram(sSimpleVS, sSimpleFS);

         int attribPosition = glGetAttribLocation(program, "position");
         checkGlError();

         int attribTexCoords = glGetAttribLocation(program, "texCoords");
         checkGlError();

         int uniformTexture = glGetUniformLocation(program, "texture");
         checkGlError();

         glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
         checkGlError();

         glUseProgram(program);
         checkGlError();

         glEnableVertexAttribArray(attribPosition);
         checkGlError();

         glEnableVertexAttribArray(attribTexCoords);
         checkGlError();

         glUniform1i(uniformTexture, texture);
         checkGlError();

         while (!mFinished) {
             checkCurrent();

             glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
             checkGlError();

             glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
             checkGlError();

             // drawQuad

             triangleVertices.position(TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_POS_OFFSET);
             glVertexAttribPointer(attribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, false,
                     TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES, triangleVertices);

             triangleVertices.position(TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_UV_OFFSET);
             glVertexAttribPointer(attribTexCoords, 3, GL_FLOAT, false,
                     TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES, triangleVertices);

             glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

             if (!mEgl.eglSwapBuffers(mEglDisplay, mEglSurface)) {
                 throw new RuntimeException("Cannot swap buffers");
             }
             checkEglError();

             try {
                 Thread.sleep(2000);
             } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                 // Ignore
             }
         }

         finishGL();
     }

     private int loadTexture(int resource) {
         int[] textures = new int[1];

         glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
         glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
         checkGlError();

         int texture = textures[0];
         glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
         checkGlError();

         glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
         glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

         glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
         glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

         Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mResources, resource);

         GLUtils.texImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, bitmap, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
         checkGlError();

         bitmap.recycle();

         return texture;
     }

     private int buildProgram(String vertex, String fragment) {
         int vertexShader = buildShader(vertex, GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
         if (vertexShader == 0) return 0;

         int fragmentShader = buildShader(fragment, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
         if (fragmentShader == 0) return 0;

         int program = glCreateProgram();
         glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
         checkGlError();

         glAttachShader(program, fragmentShader);
         checkGlError();

         glLinkProgram(program);
         checkGlError();

         int[] status = new int[1];
         glGetProgramiv(program, GL_LINK_STATUS, status, 0);
         if (status[0] != GL_TRUE) {
             String error = glGetProgramInfoLog(program);
             Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Error while linking program:\n" + error);
             glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
             glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);
             glDeleteProgram(program);
             return 0;
         }

         return program;
     }

     private int buildShader(String source, int type) {
         int shader = glCreateShader(type);

         glShaderSource(shader, source);
         checkGlError();

         glCompileShader(shader);
         checkGlError();

         int[] status = new int[1];
         glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, status, 0);
         if (status[0] != GL_TRUE) {
             String error = glGetShaderInfoLog(shader);
             Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Error while compiling shader:\n" + error);
             glDeleteShader(shader);
             return 0;
         }

         return shader;
     }

     private void checkEglError() {
         int error = mEgl.eglGetError();
         if (error != EGL10.EGL_SUCCESS) {
             Log.w(LOG_TAG, "EGL error = 0x" + Integer.toHexString(error));
         }
     }

     private void checkGlError() {
         int error = glGetError();
         if (error != GL_NO_ERROR) {
             Log.w(LOG_TAG, "GL error = 0x" + Integer.toHexString(error));
         }
     }

     private void finishGL() {
         mEgl.eglDestroyContext(mEglDisplay, mEglContext);
         mEgl.eglDestroySurface(mEglDisplay, mEglSurface);
     }

     private void checkCurrent() {
         if (!mEglContext.equals(mEgl.eglGetCurrentContext()) ||

         !mEglSurface.equals(mEgl.eglGetCurrentSurface(EGL10.EGL_DRAW))) {
             if (!mEgl.eglMakeCurrent(mEglDisplay, mEglSurface, mEglSurface, mEglContext)) {
                 throw new RuntimeException("eglMakeCurrent failed " + GLUtils.getEGLErrorString(mEgl.eglGetError()));
             }
         }
     }

     private void initGL() {
         mEgl = (EGL10) EGLContext.getEGL();

         mEglDisplay = mEgl.eglGetDisplay(EGL10.EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);
         if (mEglDisplay == EGL10.EGL_NO_DISPLAY) {
             throw new RuntimeException("eglGetDisplay failed "
                     + GLUtils.getEGLErrorString(mEgl.eglGetError()));
         }

         int[] version = new int[2];
         if (!mEgl.eglInitialize(mEglDisplay, version)) {
             throw new RuntimeException("eglInitialize failed " +
                     GLUtils.getEGLErrorString(mEgl.eglGetError()));
         }

         mEglConfig = chooseEglConfig();
         if (mEglConfig == null) {
             throw new RuntimeException("eglConfig not initialized");
         }

         mEglContext = createContext(mEgl, mEglDisplay, mEglConfig);

         mEglSurface = mEgl.eglCreateWindowSurface(mEglDisplay, mEglConfig, mSurface, null);

         if (mEglSurface == null || mEglSurface == EGL10.EGL_NO_SURFACE)
         {
             int error = mEgl.eglGetError();
             if (error == EGL10.EGL_BAD_NATIVE_WINDOW) {
                 Log.e(LOG_TAG, "createWindowSurface returned EGL_BAD_NATIVE_WINDOW.");
                 return;
             }
             throw new RuntimeException("createWindowSurface failed "
                     + GLUtils.getEGLErrorString(error));
         }

         if (!mEgl.eglMakeCurrent(mEglDisplay, mEglSurface, mEglSurface, mEglContext)) {
             throw new RuntimeException("eglMakeCurrent failed "
                     + GLUtils.getEGLErrorString(mEgl.eglGetError()));
         }

         mGL = mEglContext.getGL();
     }


     EGLContext createContext(EGL10 egl, EGLDisplay eglDisplay, EGLConfig eglConfig) {
         int[] attrib_list = { EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 2, EGL10.EGL_NONE };
         return egl.eglCreateContext(eglDisplay, eglConfig, EGL10.EGL_NO_CONTEXT, attrib_list);
     }

     private EGLConfig chooseEglConfig() {
         int[] configsCount = new int[1];
         EGLConfig[] configs = new EGLConfig[1];
         int[] configSpec = getConfig();
         if (!mEgl.eglChooseConfig(mEglDisplay, configSpec, configs, 1, configsCount)) {
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("eglChooseConfig failed " +
                     GLUtils.getEGLErrorString(mEgl.eglGetError()));
         } else if (configsCount[0] > 0) {
             return configs[0];
         }
         return null;
     }

     private int[] getConfig() {
         return new int[] {
                 EGL10.EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT,
                 EGL10.EGL_RED_SIZE, 8,
                 EGL10.EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 8,
                 EGL10.EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 8,
                 EGL10.EGL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8,
                 EGL10.EGL_DEPTH_SIZE, 0,
                 EGL10.EGL_STENCIL_SIZE, 0,
                 EGL10.EGL_NONE
         };
     }

     void finish() {
         mFinished = true;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

As @fadden mentioned earlier, you have a nice example of using the `TextureView` here: https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/TextureViewGLActivity.java.

`GLSurfaceView` and `TextureView` are mutually exclusive. I don't see a use case to have both at the same time.